# In XSL, how to split a string from comma and replace the splitted substrings to other strings?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <users>1, 2, 3</users>
</root>
```

I want to converse the IDs 1, 2, 3 to respective names, like "Albert", "Brown", "Clark", and concat them by ";". The IDs and names are fixed, so I just need to map the names to the IDs one by one simply.
I'd like to use XSLT 1.0, and the result XML in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <users>Albert;Brown;Clark</users>
</root>
```

I'm new to XSL, so any suggestions to help me get this done? Many thanks!

Comment: Where would these names come from? -- P.S. Please indicate if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: maybe follow some XSL tutorial, try something by yourself, and if it fails, add the code you tired with an explanation of what goes wrong/what you do not understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually two problems here: (1) how to tokenize the string input, and (2) how to lookup the corresponding name for each token code. Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="users">
    <user code="1">Albert</user>
    <user code="2">Brown</user>
    <user code="3">Clark</user>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="users">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>        
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="', '"/>
    <xsl:variable name="code" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
    <xsl:variable name="name" select="exsl:node-set($users)/user[@code=$code]" /> 
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$name">
            <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('No user found for code', $code)"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**: instead of a variable, you could use an external XML document for keeping the index of codes and lookup the names from there - see, for example: [XSLT- Copy node from other XML file, based on matching node value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26859749/xslt-copy-node-from-other-xml-file-based-on-matching-node-value/26870791#26870791)

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution works in my separated environment. I really want to vote for you but unfortunately I have no enough credit yet. I still have some issues to run it in the integrated compile context, but I think I'm getting close to it.